# Preciso de uma ajuda com Banco de Dados

Tags: mysql

Tenho esta tabela no meu banco de dados

[image: Tabela 1]

E preciso que em baixo do Created, tenha 1 opçao chamada Pagamento(dentro destá com duas opçoes, PAGAR(QUERO QUE JA VENHA COM ESSA DE PADRAO) e depois que eu possa alterar para (PAGO). Tem como eu fazer isso?

[image: Quero que ela venha assim, para mim depois alterar o valor PAGAR, para PAGO]

Comment: Recomendo criar uma coluna tipo `TINYINT(1)` chamada `pago`, onde você grava `0` para itens a pagar e `1` para itens pagos. Se quiser exibir outra coisa (como "pagar" para valor zero), faça isso no seu front-end, não no banco de dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso facilmente no PHPMyAdmin, fiz um exemplo, copie da maneira que está.

[image: Exemplo]

Para alterar o `PAGAR` para `PAGO`, faça:

```
UPDATE tabela SET Pagamento='PAGO' WHERE id='1';
```

Onde `tabela` você completa com o nome da sua tabela e `1` o usuário do qual você quer mudar.

Comment: E quando eu precisar alterar Para PAGO, ao invez de PAGAR, como eu faço ?

Comment: Editei minha resposta.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo agora !

Comment: Esta me retornando esse erro, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'snaps' (T_STRING) in

Comment: É algum erro com uma variável chamada 'snaps', tem nada a ver com minha resposta. Crie outra pergunta para não deixar esta ampla demais. Não se esqueça de marcar a resposta como correta.